# Как можно перезаписывать файл HTML локально?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть HTML-файл, который лежит на сетевом диске.

Ситуация такая: Пользователь запускает HTML, далее загружает посредством Javascript документ в разметку, DOM изменяется, а загруженный документ становится виден на сайте, все ок.

Но при перезагрузке HTMl, изменения не сохраняются (загруженный пользователем документ пропадает с сайта).

Вопрос: Как можно перезаписать DOM таким образом, чтобы при обновлении HTML, изменения (загруженные пользователями документы) сохранялись?

Answer (score 1):

Перезаписать html - никак. Сохранить данные - только в пределах браузера, используя [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage)